# Twig Function Pull From Repository

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to pull a complete list of users to enter into a table.

I have a function for userStatistics which i am assuming will allow me to output ALL users rows from DB.

```
public function userStatistics(){

        $stmtParams = array(
            'status' => 'Confirm'
        );

        $andWhere = ' WHERE  u.`created_at` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY';
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare("
         SELECT 
                COUNT(u.`id`) AS regCount,
                DATE_FORMAT(DATE(b.Days), '%a' ) AS regDate
            FROM 
                (SELECT a.Days 
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY AS Days
                    FROM   (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
                ) a
                WHERE a.Days >= curdate() - INTERVAL 6 DAY) b 
                LEFT JOIN `user` u ON DATE_FORMAT(u.`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d') = b.Days
                GROUP BY b.Days
                ORDER BY b.Days
        ");



        $query->execute($stmtParams);
        $result = $query->fetchAll();

        return !empty($result) ? $result : array();
        
    }
```

Currently been trying with a similar format as below.

```
{{%for user.userStatistics('$result') %}}
  
  {{ user.id }}
  
  {% endfor %}
```

```
{{%for user.userStatistics('$result') %}}
  
  {{ user.id }}
  
  {% endfor %}
```

```
{{ user.userStatistics }}
  
  {{ user.id }}
```

Both have failed with server error.

Comment: Not sure if it is a typo but `{{% and %}}` should be `{% and %}`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `userStatistics('$result')`? Not only is the syntax wrong but there is simply no need for the argument.

Comment: Why not share the error message? Also, are you sure this is only a Twig problem and working in other contexts?

Answer (score 0):

i guess your function is inside your repository class, so you can create a twig extension to call your repo function like this

```
// src/Twig/UserExtension.php
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class UserExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function getFilters(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('getUserStatistic', [$this, 'getStatistic']),
        ];
    }

    public function getStatistic()
    {
        return $this->userRepository->userStatistics();
    }
}
```

and drop it with twig

```
{% for item in getUserStatistic() %}
    ...
    {{ item.id }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```